# Plotting the clamp function on wolframalpha

Tags: function, plot, wolframalpha

It's not obvious to me how to plot on wolframalpha a function that contains conditionals, the one I have in mind is:

```
clamp lowerBound upperBound i
  | i > upperBound = upperBound
  | i < lowerBound = lowerBound
  | otherwise      = i
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used min(max(i, lowerBound), upperBound), but it does make your equation look messy.

Answer (score 0):

clip(i, {lowerBound, upperBound})